# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime: ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 7 and I successfully installed `tensorflow`. However, when running

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

in my Python IDE, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
> >>> import tensorflow as tf
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec)
> ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
>     import tensorflow as tf
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec)
> ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> above this error message when asking for help.
> ```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520428/loadlibrary-failed-with-error-1073741795-in-sdl2